# Checking if checkbox is checked, display both booleans

Tags: javascript, checkbox

I am trying to determine whether the checkbox is checked or not, but when I push the checkbox, the javascript displays:

```
false
true
```

And when I push it again it changes to

```
true
false
```

And then it continues as I push further...

How can I only display one of those?

Here is my javascript code:

```
function selected() {
  const bg = document.getElementById("myCheck").checked;

  console.log(bg);

  if (bg == 'true') {
    document.getElementById("changeBG").style.backgroundColor = 'red';
  } else {
    document.getElementById("changeBG").style.backgroundColor = 'green';
  }
}
```

Comment: Where is your code? Also, there's already a ton of examples on SO, did you search for the answer first?

Comment: It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, tracebacks, etc.). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive. Check the [tour] and [ask]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! We cannot help you with code we cannot see. Show us the code you're referring to. Also, please take the [tour], have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Also note that doing thorough research prior to posting is a requirement here at SO. I can't immediately imagine any question about how to see whether a checkbox is checked that couldn't be answered **very** quickly with a small bit of research.

Comment: Sorry guys, was too quick on the post. The code is added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is incorrect:

```
if (bg == 'true') {
```

The `checked` property gives you a boolean, not a string. `true` is a string.

Just use:

```
if (bg) {
```

Comment: Or, remove the quotes around true.

Comment: @Zammy: No, `true == 'true'` is false. [Details here](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-abstract-equality-comparison), but basically: They both end up being converted to number and you end up with `1 == NaN`, which is false.

Comment: @ScottMarcus: Yeah, but `bg` is *already* a boolean. So where do you stop? `bg == true`, or `(bg == true) == true`, or `((bg == true) == true) == true`... :-) Hence, `if (bg)` (and the converse, `if (!bg)`).

Comment: @TJ I know that. But, you didn’t put that explanation in your answer, so I was just pointing out that removing the quotes would make it a Boolean.